# Codeigniter to Generate Text View

Tags: codeigniter

I need to generate Text view of data but some links are working fine but some are not showing the results as text.

- http://www.ipaddresshost.com/downloads/ch.cidr - CH CIDR is not in Text Format
- http://www.ipaddresshost.com/downloads/af.cidr - AF CIDR is in Text Format

My Code is as under:

```
            $cidr_result    = $this->webmodel_downloads->singlecountrycidr($country_code2);
        //$this->load->helper('text');
        //$this->load->helper('file');
        //echo "# Generated ". date('Y-m-d')."\n";
        $this->output->set_content_type('text/plain', 'UTF-8');
        $this->output->set_header("Content-Type: text/plain");
        echo "# Generated ". date('Y-m-d').PHP_EOL;
        if (!empty($cidr_result)){
            foreach($cidr_result as $row){
            echo $row['value'].PHP_EOL;
            //print_r($row['value'].PHP_EOL);
            }
        }
```

Please help me, if I am doing some mistake. Thank you

Comment: check CI force_download() @ https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html#available-functions: `If you set the second parameter to NULL and $filename is an existing, readable file path, then its content will be read instead.`

Comment: Hi Vickel, Thank you for the answer but I am not downloading the file, I am getting the data from database and generating it as Text View.

Answer (score 0):

I do not Know the Technical Reason behind this but instead of using CodeIgniter function for text header, I used PHP Header and It's working Fine;

```
header ("Content-type: text/plain");
```